# Noun Phrase/absolute clause distinction

Tags: grammar, phrase-structure

What is the difference between a supplemental noun phrase and a absolute clause? In these examples and in general. Is it just the non-finite nature of the second example ?

He won at his favourite sport, the long-jump, and brought another medal home for the U.S, **the most fitting *conclusion* to his brilliant career in track and field.**

Noun phrase functioning as a supplement/ syntactically separate element.

He just stood there, **his face clearly revealing his disappointment.**

Absolute clause: called absolute because it serves no grammatical function in the sentence. It just adds supplemental information.

Comment: An absolute clause is a supplementary adjunct consisting of a non-finite clause that contains a subject and hence has no syntactic link to the main clause. Though your first example is a supplement, it is not a clause but an NP. Your second one qualifies is an absolute, since it is a subordinate non-finite clause with a subject functioning as a supplementary adjunct.